# pybliometrics returning "Error translating query"

Tags: python, scopus, pybliometrics

I was trying pybliometrics seems to be working at first but not the following code returns `"Error translating query"`

```
from pybliometrics.scopus import ScopusSearch


scopus_advanced_search = "TITLE-ABS-KEY(capacitance) AND LIMIT-TO(PUBYEAR , 2018)"

s = ScopusSearch(scopus_advanced_search, subscriber=False)
    dois = [document.doi for document in s.results]
    print(dois)
```

I was following this youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-VE3ADZvoUY&t=151s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LIMIT-TO()` is one of two keywords that the Scopus Search API doesn't accept, for whatever reason.

From the docs (https://pybliometrics.readthedocs.io/en/stable/classes/ScopusSearch.html#id1):

> query (str) – A string of the query as used in the Advanced Search on scopus.com. All fields except “INDEXTERMS()” and “LIMIT-TO()” work.